# which is the difference between the 2 codes

Tags: python

Seems the same code but i get the different results

```
# code1

a = 0
b = 1
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(a)
    a = b
    b = a + b
```

```
# code2

a, b = 0, 1
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(a)
    a,b = b, a + b
```

```
a = 0
b = 1
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(a)
    a = b
    b = a + b

print()

a, b = 0, 1
for i in range(0, 10):
    print(a)
    a,b = b, a + b
```

I expected the same output

Answer (score 0):

When you use the code 1 : first, `a` takes the value of `b` and then `b` become `a+b`, but with the new value of `a`.

In code 2, the evaluation of a and b is "simultaneous", as you use unpacking. In the same time, `a` take`b` and `b` takes the value of `a+b`, but `a` still have his initial value.

Hope that I'm clear !